# Moving the Wamp homepage Wamp64/Apache2.4.23

Tags: apache, webserver, wamp

So apparently the web is just chock full of old tutorials on how to configure this stuff that trying to find anything recent is a needle in a haystack endeavor.

What I want to do is move the Wamp64 homepage located on myIpAddres:8080/ somewhere else with local access.

I'd then like to make the root my landing page for various web project I'm doing for a class.

Problem is, moving index.php in C:/wamp64/www causes the dang thing to break. I'd like to keep it on local access for convenience but it simply can't live in the www folder where I want to put my own index.html I believe. Maybe I'm wrong though.

If THATS not possible, is there a way to make 'myIpAddress:8080/' point to a different folder, while still being able to access WAMP's index.php at a different address?

Comment: Can I ask what version of WAMPServer you are using please

Comment: Version3.0.6 the latest one.